# CMS Page Not Loading Automatically on backend

Tags: magento-1.9, products, cms-pages

On our magento backend, we have encountered an unusual issue. When we try to open a CMS page via CMS>>Pages & then select(click) page name. Now as there are two parts Left Side(Menu) & Right Side(Content), but instead of loading both sides only left side menu is shown automatically thus we have to choose desired option from menu then right side gets loaded.

This is not only happening with CMS but with product pages also. Please advise what should i do.

PS: we are using clouflare & our host says the issue is because of cloudflare

Regards

Comment: do you have something logged in browser console?

Comment: No @aurmil , there is no log on console